# "using a derogatory language" or "using derogatory language"

Tags: grammar, meaning, articles

1. By using **a** derogatory language, he really put them off.
2. By using derogatory language, he really put them off.

I think the first one is more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the third definition of [language](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/language) (in particular 3.2)

> 3. *[mass noun]* The style of a piece of writing or speech.
>
> (...)
>
> 3.2. Coarse or offensive language.

You can see that in your example *language* is a mass noun, which means it doesn't use indefinite articles.

This means that your second example is correct, whereas the first one is not.